# Can a function give information about the output at an X outside of the domain?

Tags: calculus, functions

In an FRQ for my AP Calc AB class, I was given this information for a word problem:

> Water is flowing into and out of a small reservoir. The total amount of water can be modeled by $R$, where
> $R(t) = 20-15(\sin(t^2/25))$ cubic feet, $t$ is measured in hours, and $0\leq t\leq 8$.

Part D of this question reads

> The reservoir can hold a maximum of 30 cubic feet. At what time after $t = 8$ hours will the reservoir reach its capacity?

Is this a trick question? $R(t)$'s domain was given to be between 0 and 8 hours, doesn't that mean I cannot use $R$ for any info about a $t$ greater than 8?

Comment: If you have quoted the question properly then it is indeed strange/ambiguous. Do you have an answer key to post? If you ignore the domain restriction, what answer do you get? Please [edit] the question to tell us. To format mathematics, use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Here is a [Mathjax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference); please use Mathjax for formatting mathematical formulas in the future.

Comment: The function itself makes sense for all values of $t$; so the question is probably assuming you can use the same function $R(t)$ for all $t\geq 0$ and get meaningful information out of it. Note that $R(t)$ takes values between $5$ and $35$; presumably, after it takes the value $30$, it stops being a good model.